# Is there a delegate that combines the functionality of Func<T> and Action<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

When you call a `Action<T>` you will pass in a variable of type T which will be available to the code defined in the delegate, e.g.

```
var myAction = new Action<string>(param =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is my param: '{0}'.", param);
});

myAction("Foo");

// Outputs: This is my param: 'Foo'.
```

And when you call a `Func<T>` the delegate will return a variable of type T, e.g.

```
var myFunc = new Func<string>(() =>
{
    return "Bar";
});

Console.WriteLine("This was returned from myFunc: '{0}'.", myFunc());

// Outputs: This was returned from myFunc: 'Bar'.
```

**Here's the question** -

Is there a third delegate type which will take an input parameter and *also* return a value? Something like -

```
var fooDeletegate = new FooDelegate<string, int>(theInputInt =>
{
    return "The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything is " + theInputInt;
});

Console.WriteLine(fooDeletegate(42));

// Outputs: The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything is 42
```

If such a thing doesn't exist, would it possible to use `Action<Func<sting>>` for this sort of functionality?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're looking for [`Func<T, TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx), or one of its [**15** other](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd402862.aspx) overloads.

Comment: I've had coworkers complain about the fact that Func<T0..15,TResult> only supports up to 16 arguments and they couldn't therefore use it in their code :(

Comment: Gosh, I can't _believe_ I've never seen that overload before! I'm sorry for what now seems like a stupid/newbie question. And of course, thank you for your response :)

Comment: @Florian Doyon - .NET 3.5 only had Func<> generic "overloads" for up to 4 parameters and a return. That did often limit its usefulness. .NET 4.0 expanded to 16; if you are passing more than 16 parameters to ANY managed method, you should re-think your architecture.

Comment: @KeithS I couldn't agree more... still considering sending some samples to the DailyWTF :)

Answer (score 2):

There are `Func<>` overloads with [more than zero] parameters `Func<TParam, TReturn>`, `Func<TParam1, TParam2, TReturn>`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this with `new Func<inputType1, inputType2, inputType3, outputType>()`. This is possible with 0 to 16 input parameters. You will find the different `Func` overloads in [the System namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxcx7skw.aspx).

Comment: Not quite 0 to n inputs, but 0 to 16 should meet most needs. Now all they need is a `params` keyword for generic type parameters and it WOULD be 0 to n.

Comment: yeah you are right. I don't think anyone will need more than 16, but i will change that in my post.